# Is intellij-jdk the official JDK binary distribution for Android?

Tags: java, android, jetbrains-ide

Google (company that makes Android) has declared:

> A copy of the latest OpenJDK comes bundled with Android Studio 2.2 and higher, and this is the JDK version we recommend you use for your Android projects.
>
> Source: https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config.html#jdk (checked February 26, 2020)

Meanwhile, JetBrains (company that <strike>makes</strike> **build the core** of Android Studio) has stated (May 10, 2018):

> We have our own OpenJDK builds that are published here: https://bintray.com/jetbrains/intellij-jdk/
>
> Source: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000524544-is-jetbrains-using-a-special-version-of-openJDK- (checked February 26, 2020)

**Is the intellij-jdk binary distribution of Java the official standard distribution for building Android projects?**

Comment: *"Meanwhile, JetBrains (company that makes Android Studio)..."* Nope. JetBrains does not make Android Studio; JetBrains makes IntelliJ IDEA and Android Studio is based on IDEA code-base. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Studio

Comment: I browsed through the Android Studio code base and found this old reference: 

"http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html" in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/refs/heads/master/native/installer/win/setup_android_studio.nsi

But since most people use JDK8 for Android it still feels like an unsolved problem...